# Mesclar consultas de banco de dados diferentes

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

***"É possível juntar informações de tabelas de outros Bancos de dados?"***

Essa dúvida surgiu quando precisava fazer uma pesquisa fazer um comparação de dados em tabelas de lojas diferentes, *cada loja tem seu BD*, onde precisava comparar a média de produtos vendidos, o que sai mais em cada loja, quantos clientes fazem autenticação, de forma rápida sem precisar rodar um código em vários lugares e depois unir os dados separadamente.

Baseado nesse problema, a dúvida é:

> Como posso coletar e comparar dados de outros bancos de dados onde as tabelas tenham a mesma estrutura?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De certo é possível fazer uma busca em Bancos de dados diferentes ao mesmo tempo. para acessar bancos de dados diferentes basta passar dentro do select o database, a table e os campos que deseja pegar.

`SELECT banco_01.vendas.* FROM banco_01.vendas;`

Mas como são tabelas diferentes, apenas o `select` não seria o suficiente para listar as informações corretamente.

Um jeito de se resolver isso, é criando uma `procedure` onde para que criaria uma view ou uma tabela temporária com as informações. Ou pode-se usar o comando `union`, *o comando union faz a união de **N** `selects` e retorna um registro com todas as informações*.

Para selecionar a quantidade de compras feitas em cada loja bastaria utilizar o comando `union` dessa forma:

```
SELECT
    count(loja_01.vendas.id) as total_vendas
FROM
    loja_01.vendas
UNION
SELECT
    count(loja_02.vendas.id) as total_vendas
FROM loja_02.vendas;
```